# how to add arguments to menu links?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to add some arguments to the links of my menu items

For example I have a menu item with the following url as target:

```
node/add/product&catalog=0
```

However it doesn't work because what I get is:

```
node/add/product%2526catalog%3D0
```

How can I get rid of numeric codes and just display the url as it is ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the '&' with a '?', like so:

```
node/add/product?catalog=0
```

This way, the Drupal menu system won't escape the query part of the url. Additional parameters can be added using '&':

```
node/add/product?catalog=0&destination=...
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using node/add/product/catalog/0

Perhaps that might help?